# Clojure: Idiomatic/clean way to avoid NPE in a monad-like way

Tags: clojure

I'm a little chagrinned that some of the built-in Clojure functions have what seems to me to be an inconsistent behavior.

I'm trying to do this:

```
 (let [kwns (namespace (keyword v))]
   ...)
```

in a context where v might be `nil`. The `keyword` function works as I'd expect (returns `nil`), but namespace throws a NPE.

I was under the impression that monads were not often used in Clojure since nil-punning seems to be the idiomatic form (as [this article](http://www.lispcast.com/nil-punning) carries on about at length).

I expected kwns to come out nil, not throw an NPE. When this inconsistency raises its ugly head, what is the recommended way to keep the code clean....peppering `nil` checks into my code is *not* the answer I'm wanting, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would `some->` work for you?

```
 user=> (doc some->)
 -------------------------
 clojure.core/some->
 ([expr & forms])
 Macro
   When expr is not nil, threads it into the first form (via ->),
   and when that result is not nil, through the next etc
 nil
 user=> (some-> nil keyword namespace)
 nil
 user=> (some-> "user/a" keyword namespace)
 "user"
```

Comment: Perfect...I knew there had to be something!